# Why an aws glue Workflow have empty default run properties and no graph, when accessed from an sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue, aws-java-sdk

Can anyone explain why an aws glue Workflow would have empty default run properties and no graph, when accessed from an sdk?   When I view the same workflow on the aws console I can see the ui representation of the graph and the run properties.
Yet when I access the same workflow via sdks (tried java and boto3) the Workflow object show empty default run properties and no graph.  The accessor methods for these attributes return empty objects or null.  For example
with the java sdk

`myWorkflow.getGraph()` returns null

I know the workflow has a several nodes and I have run and modified the workflow many times via the console.

I've tried to research if this is a permissions issue but I can't find anything to back that up and I don't get an error.   Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So there is a "IncludeGraph" parameter in the getWorkflow request.  The default of which is False.  So to get the graph returned with your workflow you must set the parameter to true.

in Java:
`......yourWorkflowRequest.withIncludeGraph(true)`

in boto3:
`.get_workflow(Name='the_workflow', IncludeGraph=True)`